# How to reference local Kafka and Zookeeper config on Spring Cloud Dataflow "Cloudfoundry" server start

Tags: java, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, pcfdev

Here's is what I have successfully done so far on SCDF Local Server

1. I have successfully deployed SCDF server on my local and also I have used Kafka and Zookeeper config parameters with it i.e

**mymac$ java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar
 --spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9092
 --spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=localhost:2181**

I was able to create my stream

1. `ingest = producer-app > :broker1`
2. `filter = :broker1 > filter-app > :broker2`

---

Now I need help to do the exact same thing on PCFDev

1. I have my PCFDEv running
2. I have to deploy SCDF-Cloudfoundry jar with my local kafka and zookeeper parameters to pcfDev but when I do the following steps it gives me an error that its

**1.1) cf push -f manifest-scdf.yml --no-start -p /XXX/XXX/XXX/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar -k 1500M**

this runs good...no problem. but 1.2

**1.2) cf start dataflow-server --spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=host.pcfdev.io:9092 --spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=host.pcfdev.io:2181**

gives me this error:--

**Incorrect Usage: unknown flag `spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers'**

below is my manifest-scdf.yml file

```
---
instances: 1                        
memory: 2048M                         
applications:                         
  - name: dataflow-server                   
    host: dataflow-server                  
    services:                       
      - redis                      
      - rabbit                         
    env:                          
      SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_URL: https://api.local.pcfdev.io
      SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ORG: pcfdev-org
      SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_SPACE: pcfdev-space
      SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_DOMAIN: local.pcfdev.io
      SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_USERNAME: admin
      SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_PASSWORD: admin
      SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_SKIP_SSL_VALIDATION: true
      SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_STREAM_SERVICES: rabbit
      MAVEN_REMOTE_REPOSITORIES_REPO1_URL: https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot
      SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_DISK: 512
      SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_STREAM_BUILDPACK: java_buildpack
      spring.cloud.deployer.cloudfoundry.stream.memory: 400         
      spring.cloud.dataflow.features.tasks-enabled: true            
      spring.cloud.dataflow.features.streams-enabled: true
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: 0

i see you have specified SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_STREAM_SERVICES: rabbit and passing the kafka server url as part of start up . To connect to kafka why do we need rabbit as service ?Also is the SERVICES option mandatory ? ie can i just have the kafka server details with out specifying a service ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few options to supply Kafka credentials to Stream-apps in PCF.

#### 1. Kafka CUPs

This option allows you to create CUPs for an external Kafka-service. While deploying the stream, you can then supply the coordinates to each application either individually as described in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-ups) or you can supply them as [global properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-global-properties) for all the stream-apps deployed by the SCDF-server.

#### 2. Inline properties

Instead of extracting from CUPs, you can also directly supply the HOST/PORT while deploying the stream. Again, this can be applied globally, too.

`stream deploy myTest --properties "app.*.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=<HOST>:9092,app.*.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=<HOST>:2181`

*Note: The HOST must be reachable for the stream-apps; o'wise, it ill continue to connect to localhost and potentially fail since the apps are running inside a VM.*

Comment: Thank you Sabby. quick query--"How do you supply them globally after you have created the CUP?"

Comment: 1) Does it need to be during the cf start dataflow-server command or

2) something else. Just a lil confused. I'd prefer it to be globally supplied since it'll be tough to supply as inline arguments if the number of apps increases

Comment: You'd supply that as SAJ env-var. Something like: `cf set-env <SERVER_NAME> SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON {"spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers": "<HOST>:<PORT>","spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes": "<HOST>:<PORT>"}`

Comment: See [this comment](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/rabbit/issues/1#issuecomment-287509751) to set custom rabbit coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is coming from the CF CLI, it's interpreting those (I'm assuming environment) variables you're providing as flags to the `cf start` command and failing.

You could either provide them in your `manifest.yml` or set their values manually using the CLI's `cf set-env` command by doing something like this:

```
cf set-env dataflow-server spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers host.pcfdev.io:9092

cf set-env dataflow-server spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes host.pcfdev.io:2181
```

After you've set them they should be picked up when you run `cf start dataflow-server`.

Relevant CLI docs:
http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/set-env.html